# Libgdx android - Memory Leak

Tags: android, libgdx

I see that onCreate and onResume of libgdx AndroidApplication (In case you are wondering `com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication` extends from Activity and not `android.app.Application`) [In onCreate of libgdx's AndroidApplication](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication.java#L164) the instance of current activity is saved as a static field in Gdx class, and the static reference is never dereferenced anywhere (not in onDestroy or anywhere).

This is causing a memory leak in my application as I have many Activities and only one of them extends from com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication (the one that contains game)

I want to know what is recommended by libgdx guys? Should we remove the reference in onDestroy/orPause ourselves?

Added same issue in libgdx issue tracker here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3579

Comment: onCreate and onDestroy are only ever called once per application lifecycle.  Setting a static value, that exists only in the scope of that application, a static value which is destroyed when the application is destroyed, should not be leaking memory.  What makes you think that this is the culprit, as it seems highly unlikely that this is the case.  Have you run a debugger that indicates as such?  If so, then you should provide that log on the issue tracker.

Comment: Hey @nhydock The AndroidApplication class in libgdx extends from activity. It doesn't extend from the android.app.Application. Its the one which our activity extends. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication.java#L59  So if we want to have other activities in our game (Other activities have native android views) , then there is a memory leak.

Comment: Edited the question to be more clear.